# Unable to get current latitude and longitude In Angular

Tags: angular, latitude-longitude, currentlocation

I am trying to get user current location like city but here I am not getting proper latitude and longitude as per the current location.
it is showing some other district lat and lng and sometime some other state.
I do not know why this happening.
Whatever code  I am using these are below.

```js
getLocation1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                const lat = position.coords.latitude;
                const lng = position.coords.longitude;
                this.http.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=mykey&latlng="+lat+","+lng+"&result_type=administrative_area_level_2&sensor=false")

            //this.http.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?&latlng="+lat+","+lng+"&sensor=false&types=(regions)&key=Myapikey")
                .map(response => response.json()).take(5).toPromise().then(result => {          
                    resolve(result);            
                    console.log(result)
                }).catch(err => {
                    reject(err);
                });
            });
        } else {
            reject("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    });
}
```

Please help what would be best to get proper lat and lng in Angular.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So did you see any thing in the console ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. actually I am getting lat and lng but wrong, I mean getting of  some other place

Comment: So where did you expected to get the data. I'm still dont understand what you mean

Comment: ok, Let me tell,   actually it is not showing lat and lng of my place where I am right now instead of that it showing lat&lng of some other place which is other state

Comment: Then I think there are some mismatch in your code or some virtual network make the location not showing correct place

Comment: Please  I have posted code above

Comment: Refer: https://www.codementor.io/brijmcq/angular-display-current-location-using-google-map-fnl3tosdq

Comment: Hi, actually my requirement is little different